# ActiveMQ Request TimeOut

Tags: c#, exception, activemq-classic

*I preface this post by saying I have only recently been working with ActiveMQ*

I am currently working on a project that uses ActiveMQ as a messaging framework between two endpoints. It is used in a relatively straightforward manner. Client 1 puts JSON into Client 2's queue, and vice versa. Each client listens on their queue and processes messages.

On the C# side, Apache's NMS library is being employed to enact the messaging. Something I've noticed showing up in logs is:

```
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.RequestTimedOutException: Synchronous Request Timed out after [20000] milliseconds
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection.SyncRequest(Command command, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Session.DoSend(ActiveMQDestination destination, ActiveMQMessage message, MessageProducer producer, MemoryUsage producerWindow, TimeSpan sendTimeout)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.MessageProducer.Send(IDestination destination, IMessage message, MsgDeliveryMode deliveryMode, MsgPriority priority, TimeSpan timeToLive, Boolean specifiedTimeToLive)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.MessageProducer.Send(IDestination destination, IMessage message)
```

My interpretation of this error is that ActiveMQ tried to perform the actual Send (blocking) for 20 seconds before finally giving up. The interesting thing to me is that I send log entries after that would indicate successful message send.

Could someone with more ActiveMQ experience explain this to me as well as point me to any best practices? I am not sure how to diagnose this and/or how to institute a heartbeat mechanism that can confirm the other Client is really "there". I've experiments with ping messages that get sent to one client and instantly put back into the originating client's queue but in my tests it seems that I will be going along receiving messages in under a second and then at some point, the messages stop being received for up to a minute.

Comment: Are you using the failover URI to connect to the broker.  Have you checked for resource limit overage in the broker logs.

Comment: We are using failover. Bear with me I am still very green on this technology, do you mean the ActiveMQ log on the server?

Comment: If you are using failover, the client might reconnect and successfully send the message once reconnected (to another broker or the same). Look into the AMQ broker logs for clues.

Comment: I think you are on to something because we don't see this when not using failover. How should one handle this case? We are using it as a pinging mechanism to send to one person's queue and they immediately send it back to our queue. We set a threshold of 60 sec with receive and we still see it occurring.